# ansible ssh error during pre ping to cisco device

Tags: ansible, ping

Could not connect to Cisco router using Ansible 2.3.1.0

straight from linux ssh cisco@172.1.1.2 works

but the ansible -m ping all doesnt.
Maybe it's clear where could be a problem from this output:

```
[osboxes@osboxes ~]$ ansible -m ping servers -vvv

Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
META: ran handlers
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/ping.py
<172.1.1.2> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: cisco
<172.1.1.2> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o User=cisco -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/osboxes/.ansible/cp/1ed8487ad4 172.1.1.2 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
<172.1.1.2> (0, '\r\nLine has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'echo ~ && sleep 0\'"', '')
<172.1.1.2> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: cisco
<172.1.1.2> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o User=cisco -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/osboxes/.ansible/cp/1ed8487ad4 172.1.1.2 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1499178341.35-260752414357590 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1499178341.35-260752414357590="` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1499178341.35-260752414357590 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<172.1.1.2> (0, '\r\nLine has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'"\'"\'echo ~ && sleep 0\'"\'"\'"/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1499178341.35-260752414357590 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1499178341.35-260752414357590="` echo Line has invalid autocomma"', 'muxclient: master hello exchange failed\r\n')
<172.1.1.2> PUT /tmp/tmpacZGSy TO "` echo Line has invalid autocomma"/ping.py
<172.1.1.2> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 sftp -o BatchMode=no -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o User=cisco -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/osboxes/.ansible/cp/1ed8487ad4 '[172.1.1.2]'
<172.1.1.2> (255, '', 'Connection closed\r\n')
172.1.1.2 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Connection closed\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
```

thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
ansible_connection = local
```

To either `[all:vars]` or `[servers:var]` in your inventory file:
`/[path]/ansible/hosts`

If needed you can also add:

```
ansible_ssh_pass=some_password
ansible_ssh_user=username
```

To the inventory file

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you're connecting to a Cisco device. As IOS doesn't offer a `/bin/sh` command, you won't be able to use ansible's `ping` module (or any other standard module, for that matter).

You could however try to do something with the [`raw` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/raw_module.html), which allows to send commands without going through the module subsystem. There seem to be [some bugs](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/3332) related to that module when it comes to Cisco devices, though, so you might need to update to a very recent ansible version.